# Cannot sort DDL using multiple fields in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to sort a dynamically created DDL.  This DDL has a combination of fields being Location1, Location2, Location3.

The code used to create the DDL is as follows:

```
        ddlLocation.Items.Clear();
        dtLocation = dataSource.GetFilteredRiskInfo("location");
        ddlLocation.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All", "-1"));
        foreach (DataRow row in dtLocation.Rows)
        {
            if (this.ddlLocation.Items.FindByText(row["Location1"].ToString()) == null)
                this.ddlLocation.Items.Add(new ListItem(row["Location1"].ToString()));
            if (this.ddlLocation.Items.FindByText(row["Location2"].ToString()) == null)
                this.ddlLocation.Items.Add(new ListItem(row["Location2"].ToString()));
            if (this.ddlLocation.Items.FindByText(row["Location3"].ToString()) == null)
                this.ddlLocation.Items.Add(new ListItem(row["Location3"].ToString()));
        }
```

The following code works for location1 (I think).

```
[DisplayColumn("location","Location1")]
public partial class Location
{
}
```

I have been researching how to add multiple fields ie: location2 & location3, it does not work.  The code itself shows an error for Location1 & Location2 ("The name 'Location1' does not exist in the current context")

```
    [DisplayColumn("location","SortColumn")]
public partial class Location
{
    public string SortColumn
    {
        get { return Location1 + Location2; }
    }
}
```

All help will be much apprecaited.

The list of locations need to be as follows.  Say the locations have the following data.

Location1:
Sydney, Wollongong Perth

Location2:
Adelaide, Northern Territory

Location3:
Brisbane, Canberra, Hobart

I need the combined list to look as follows:
Adelaide
Brisbane
Canberra
Hobart
Northern Territory
Perth
Sydney
Wollongong

My code now looks as follows:

```
            ddlLocation.Items.Clear();
        // new table to combine the 3 columns of dtLocation into a one column datatable
        DataTable sortedDt = new DataTable();
        dtLocation = dataSource.GetFilteredRiskInfo("location");
        sortedDt.Columns.Add("Location");

        // combining columns
        foreach (DataRow row in dtLocation.Rows)
        {
            sortedDt.Rows.Add(row["Location1"]);
            sortedDt.Rows.Add(row["Location2"]);
            sortedDt.Rows.Add(row["Location3"]);
        }

        // now sort these now that they're all in the same column
        sortedDt.DefaultView.Sort = "Location";
        sortedDt = sortedDt.DefaultView.ToTable(); // should be the new sorted table

        // now your original code, but modified to populate the ddl with the new sorted data


        ddlLocation.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All", "-1"));
        foreach (DataRow row in sortedDt.Rows)
        {
            this.ddlLocation.Items.Add(new ListItem(row["Location"].ToString()));
        }
```

Now the list is in alphabetical order but has duplicate entries.  I need to be able to remove the duplicates/make the entries distinct.

Comment: Why don't you simply merge a string of all three locations and then add the string into ddl?

Comment: You want List item to display `Location1 + Location2`?

Comment: Why have you not sorted in the call to GetFilteredRiskInfo()?  Then when you loop through the DataRows it is presorted.

Answer (score 0):

Not only should you presort it in GetFilteredRiskInfo as FrankO suggests, but it sounds like you have to combine the 3 location columns into one.  If you can do that in GetFilteredRiskInfo it might be cleaner, if not you can try combining the columns and sorting in code with something like this:

```
    // new table to combine the 3 columns of dtLocation into a one column datatable
    DataTable sortedDt = new DataTable();
    sortedDt.Columns.Add("Location");

    // combining columns
    foreach (DataRow row in dtLocation.Rows)
    {
        sortedDt.Rows.Add(row["Location1"]);
        sortedDt.Rows.Add(row["Location2"]);
        sortedDt.Rows.Add(row["Location3"]);
    }

    // now sort these now that they're all in the same column
    sortedDt.DefaultView.Sort = "Location";
    sortedDt = sortedDt.DefaultView.ToTable(); // should be the new sorted table

    // now your original code, but modified to populate the ddl with the new sorted data
    ddlLocation.Items.Clear();
    dtLocation = dataSource.GetFilteredRiskInfo("location");
    ddlLocation.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All", "-1"));
    foreach (DataRow row in sortedDt.Rows)
    {
            this.ddlLocation.Items.Add(new ListItem(row["Location"].ToString()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks both FronkO (I now have sorted lists on all my drop downs) and madamission (for the extra help with the locations sorting).  Between the 2 of you and some help from the internet I now have it working.  The working code is as follows:

```
           //Location
        ddlLocation.Items.Clear();
        // new table to combine the 3 columns of dtLocation into a one column datatable
        DataTable sortedDt = new DataTable();
        sortedDt.Columns.Add("Location");
        dtLocation = dataSource.GetFilteredRiskInfo("location");

        // combining columns
        foreach (DataRow row in dtLocation.Rows)
        {
            sortedDt.Rows.Add(row["Location1"]);
            sortedDt.Rows.Add(row["Location2"]);
            sortedDt.Rows.Add(row["Location3"]);
        }

        // now make them distinct & sort them now that they're all in the same column
        sortedDt = sortedDt.DefaultView.ToTable(/*distinct*/ true);
        sortedDt.DefaultView.Sort = "Location";
        sortedDt = sortedDt = sortedDt.DefaultView.ToTable();

        // now your original code, but modified to populate the ddl with the new sorted data
        ddlLocation.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All", "-1"));
        foreach (DataRow row in sortedDt.Rows)
        {
            this.ddlLocation.Items.Add(new ListItem(row["Location"].ToString()));
        }
```